# Flutter delays the display of a dialog box

Tags: flutter

Flutter delays the display of a dialog box. It only wants to be displayed on the first page, but not on the second page

- I tried to add Overlay to first page, but it does not work
- I don't want to show the dialog on the second page. how to control overlay?

Demo

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TWOverlayTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TWOverlayTestApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildContent(context);
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("TWOverlayTestApp"),
        ),
        body: const TWContentView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

first page content

```dart
class TWContentView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TWContentView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TWContentView> createState() => _TWContentViewState();
}

class _TWContentViewState extends State<TWContentView> {
  BuildContext? pageOverlayContext;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          _showAlert();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _buildJumpSecondPage(),
        _buildPageOverlay(),
      ],
    );
  }

  _showAlert() {
    if (pageOverlayContext == null) return;
    showDialog(
      context: pageOverlayContext!,
      useRootNavigator: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('tip title'),
          content: const Text('this is tip content'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('ensure'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _buildJumpSecondPage() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.orange,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const TWOverlaySecondPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Center(
          child: Text("jump second page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPageOverlay() {
    return Overlay(
      initialEntries: [
        OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) {
            pageOverlayContext = context;
            return Container();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

TWOverlaySecondPage

```dart
class TWOverlaySecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TWOverlaySecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("TWOverlaySecondPage"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now

[image]

Comment: You should avoid creating functions that return a widget.  https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `boolean` flag `shouldShowDialog` and set it to `false` when navigating to the second page. In the `_showAlert` method, check the flag before showing the dialog.

or you can check if the current route is the first page before showing the dialog by using `ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent`:

```dart
if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent == true) {
  _showAlert();
}
```

This will ensure that the dialog is displayed only on the first page and not on the second page.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/of.html

Comment: if it must to show on page 1 ?